# How to add dynamic row ( with dropdown in column ) when we have an edit option already implemented in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid which contains dropdown as few column values. I could edit the particular grid it is giving the proper dropdown values but when I try to add a new row dynamically to the grid it shows error .

Live example [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/OMINUtum)

What I am looking for is when i click on the add new item button in the grid it should add a new row with the given dropdown values.

I have tried to add   `toolbar: ["create"]` for creating new toolbar 
Inside data bound event I have tried to capture the button click and tried to add a new row but nothing is working

```
dataBound: function (e) {
            $('.k-grid-add').unbind("click");

            $('.k-grid-add').bind("click", function () {
                dataSource.add({ brandId: 0, name: "" });
                var data = dataSource.data();
            });
        },
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to add `data.` in the templates in order to access a desired data property. Change your templates to:

```
template: "#= brandName(data.brandId) #"
```

and

```
template: "#= modelName(data.modelId) #"
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/OMINUtum/3)